# Python and Selenium: how to pull the data from the web text which has no id, class?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I had an website to pull information from. 
For example, http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/alaska-native-medical-center/info/8500

I need to pull the information and save into CSV file. For example,

Category: General Hospitals
Name: Alaska Native Medical Center
Address: 4315 Diplomacy Drive

Phone: (907) 563-2662
City: Anchorage
State: Alaska

But the problem now is that I cannot locate these information.
The web code is as below:

```
<b>Category:</b>
  General Hospitals
<br>
<b>Address:</b>
  4315 Diplomacy Drive
<br>
<b>Subcontinent and Continent:</b>
  North America, America
<br>
```

Please give me some suggestions or code to help me get those text.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, after a quick glance at the website, it looks like the data you want scraped is located in a `<table>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/alaska-native-medical-center/info/8500')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
start = soup.find('em')

for b in start.find_next_siblings('b'):

        print(b.text, b.next_sibling.strip())
```

out:

```
Category: General Hospitals
Address: 4315 Diplomacy Drive
Subcontinent and Continent: North America            , 
            America
Country: United States
Phone (907) 563-2662
Website: 
City:  
State:  
Email: 
Latitude: 61.1827
Longitude: -149.80009
Zip Code: 99508
Contact Address: 4315 Diplomacy Dr, Anchorage, AK 99508, United States
Latitude in Degree, Minute, Second [Direction]: 61° 10' 57" N
```

Comment: Do note that this leaves out City and State, which are visible on the original web page.  Question also requests that Name be returned.

Comment: Yeah, City and State didn't show up. It is very confusing

Comment: @PeterCui: City and State are inside of `font` tags.  Change `print` to `print(b.text, b.find_next('font').text if b.text.startswith(('City:', 'State:')) else b.next_sibling.strip())`.